# Problems using sed escaping characters

Tags: regex, bash, sed

I have a file that looks like this:

```
hairgrayingB    ~intron KCND3|KCND3-IT1(-17.36kb)
hairgrayingB    ~intron KCND3|KCND3-IT1(-15.28kb)
hairgrayingB    ~intron KCND3|KCND3-IT1(-14.72kb)
hairgrayingB    ~intron KCND3|KCND3-IT1(-13.4kb)
hairgrayingB    ~intron KCND3|KCND3-IT1(-12.28kb)
hairgrayingB    ~intron KCND3|KCND3-IT1(-7.076kb)
hairgrayingB    ~intron CACNA1E
hairgrayingB    ~intron CACNA1E
.
.
.
```

I want to delete everything inside brackets (including the brackets) on every row so I used this command on my text editor and it worked, but not using sed:

In text editor:

```
\([-,+][0-9]+.[0-9]+kb\)
```

On sed:

```
sed '/\([-,+][0-9]+.[0-9]+kb\)/d' infile
```

I just get the same output.

Thank you.

Comment: how should the expected output look like? is `( ... )` always at the end of the line? If so, `sed 's/(.*$//' file` should make. Also, brackets are `[ ]`, whereas `( )` are parentheses.

Comment: Hi @fedorqui your simple line worked. Why isn't mine working? thank you!

Comment: You should start posting what exactly you want and what condition does the text between parentheses must fulfill (if any). Then we can talk about your command.

Comment: Yes, do you just want to remove all text in parentheses or only `+-` and numbers? Oh, and @fedorqui actually, parentheses can also be called brackets, strictly speaking. See [definition 3c.](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/bracket)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To print lines without (...):

```
sed -r '/\([-+]?[0-9]+.[0-9]+kb\)/d' filename
```

Output:

```
hairgrayingB    ~intron CACNA1E
hairgrayingB    ~intron CACNA1E
```

To remove (...):

```
sed -r 's/\([-+]?[0-9]+\.[0-9]+kb\)//' filename
```

Output:

```
hairgrayingB    ~intron KCND3|KCND3-IT1
hairgrayingB    ~intron KCND3|KCND3-IT1
hairgrayingB    ~intron KCND3|KCND3-IT1
hairgrayingB    ~intron KCND3|KCND3-IT1
hairgrayingB    ~intron KCND3|KCND3-IT1
hairgrayingB    ~intron KCND3|KCND3-IT1
hairgrayingB    ~intron CACNA1E
hairgrayingB    ~intron CACNA1E
```

`-r` is used for extended-regex.

If (...) is always at the last:

```
sed 's/(.*$//' filename
```

Answer (score 2):

There's no need to escape the parentheses unless you use `-r`. `(` and `)` have no meaning in BRE which is the default `sed` regex flavor. So, you could simply do

```
sed 's/([^)]*)//g'
```

The general rule in regular expressions is "less is more". Avoid making the expression too specific. If you want to delete everything inside parentheses, just use `[^)]*` as I did above. There's no need to define numbers and signs.

Comment: @EdMorton thanks :) As for the `g`, sure you do, what if there are more than 1 set of parentheses per line? The OP's example input only has one but the question was "I want to delete everything inside brackets (including the brackets) on every row[...]".

Comment: @EdMorton unless the OP clarifies, I will answer what they asked :). Note that their sed code simply fails, for example, the only thing we can rely on here is the text in the question. This approach works on both the posted sample and on the general case. Removing the `g` would simply make it break for cases where there are >1 parentheses since that would remove the 1st. If anything, you could replace `g` with `sed 's/([^)]*)$//'` but, again, I'd rather not make assumptions about what the OP _meant_ to say.

Comment: Hmm, I think we can also rely on him showing us the format of his input file and, more importantly, the command that works in his text editor but OK, it's not going to hurt to leave the `g` at the end. It's still the best solution either way.

Answer (score 1):

Given your posted sample input/output all you need is:

```
$ sed 's/(.*//' file
hairgrayingB    ~intron KCND3|KCND3-IT1
hairgrayingB    ~intron KCND3|KCND3-IT1
hairgrayingB    ~intron KCND3|KCND3-IT1
hairgrayingB    ~intron KCND3|KCND3-IT1
hairgrayingB    ~intron KCND3|KCND3-IT1
hairgrayingB    ~intron KCND3|KCND3-IT1
hairgrayingB    ~intron CACNA1E
hairgrayingB    ~intron CACNA1E
```

or:

```
$ cut -d\( -f1 file
hairgrayingB    ~intron KCND3|KCND3-IT1
hairgrayingB    ~intron KCND3|KCND3-IT1
hairgrayingB    ~intron KCND3|KCND3-IT1
hairgrayingB    ~intron KCND3|KCND3-IT1
hairgrayingB    ~intron KCND3|KCND3-IT1
hairgrayingB    ~intron KCND3|KCND3-IT1
hairgrayingB    ~intron CACNA1E
hairgrayingB    ~intron CACNA1E
```